# how to select all td apart of last child using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to figure out code that will allow me wrap content inside td apart from last child

What I have here does not work.

```
$('.ResultsRow2 td:not(last-child)').wrapInner('<div style="padding-top:4px"></div>')
```

Could you please advice me how to select all columns apart of the last one?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last-child selector needs a colon in front of it.

```
$('.ResultsRow2 td:not(:last-child)')...
```